# Angular9-BehaviorSubject is being called multiple times when I switch between channels, even I'm unsubscribing my behavior subject from destroy method

Tags: angular, angular9, behaviorsubject

I'm using Socket.io and Angular 9 to build chat functionality. As shown below, I created a service and called for socket connection and event handling.

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { chatUrl } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ChatService {
  private socket;
  loaded: boolean;
  token: any;
  public channelsCounts: any = [];
  public channelError = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public channelPostPermissionDenided = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public channelHistory = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public channelMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public channelMessageReply = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public channelReaction = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public channelsCountsSubject: any = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  public channelSetting = new BehaviorSubject(null);


  constructor(public storageServ: StorageService) { }

  establishSocketConnection = (userId) => {
    this.socket = io(`${chatUrl}/chat`, {
      path: '/socket.io',
      query: {
        user: userId,
      },
      transports: ['websocket'],
    });

    this.socket.on('channel-error', (errorMessage) => {
      this.channelError.next(errorMessage);
    });

    this.socket.on('post-message-permission-denied', (permission) => {
      this.channelPostPermissionDenided.next(permission);
    });

    this.socket.on('channel-history', (channel: any) => {
      this.channelError.next(null);
      this.channelPostPermissionDenided.next(null);
      this.channelHistory.next(channel);
    });

    this.socket.on('message-local', (message: any) => {
      this.updateChannelCount(message.channelId, message.authorId);
      this.channelMessage.next(message);
    });

    this.socket.on('message-reply', (message: any) => {
      this.updateChannelCount(message.channelId, message.authorId);
      this.channelMessageReply.next(message);
    });

    this.socket.on('reaction', (message: any) => {
      this.channelReaction.next(message);
    });

    this.socket.on('update-channel-setting', (channel: any) => {
      this.channelSetting.next(channel);
    });
  }

  public clearChannelHistory(){
    this.channelHistory.next(null);
  }

  public pingOnChannelsLoaded() {
    const channelsCounts = !!localStorage.getItem('channelsCounts') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('channelsCounts') || '[]') : [];
    this.channelsCounts = channelsCounts;
    this.channelsCountsSubject.next(channelsCounts);
  }

  public updateChannelCount = (channelId, author) => {
    const loggedInUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authorId') || '{}');
    const activatedChannel = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('channelId') || '{}');
    if (loggedInUser && author._id !== loggedInUser.id && (!activatedChannel || activatedChannel._id !== channelId)) {
      const channelIndex = this.channelsCounts.findIndex(c => c.channelId === channelId);
      if (channelIndex !== -1) {
        this.channelsCounts[channelIndex].count = this.channelsCounts[channelIndex].count + 1;
      } else {
        this.channelsCounts.push({
          channelId,
          count: 1
        });
      }
      this.storageServ.set('channelsCounts', JSON.stringify(this.channelsCounts));
      this.channelsCountsSubject.next(this.channelsCounts);
    }
  }

  // emit events
  public emitChannelHistory = (channelId, page) => {
    const channelsCounts = !!localStorage.getItem('channelsCounts') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('channelsCounts') || '[]') : [];
    this.channelsCounts = channelsCounts;

    const channelIndex = this.channelsCounts.findIndex(c => c.channelId === channelId);
    if (channelIndex !== -1) {
      this.channelsCounts[channelIndex].count = 0;
    } else {
      this.channelsCounts.push({
        channelId,
        count: 0
      });
    }
    this.channelsCountsSubject.next(this.channelsCounts);
    this.storageServ.set('channelsCounts', JSON.stringify(this.channelsCounts));

    if (this.socket) {
      this.socket.emit('load-channel-history', channelId, page);
    }
  }

  public emitMessage = (message, authorId, channelId) => {
    if (this.socket) {
      this.socket.emit('message', message, authorId, channelId);
    }
  }

  public emitMessageReply = (message, parentId, authorId, channelId) => {
    if (this.socket) {
      this.socket.emit('message-reply', message, parentId, authorId, channelId);
    }
  }

  public emitReaction = (channelId, threadId, userId, emoji) => {
    if (this.socket) {
      this.socket.emit('reaction', channelId, threadId, userId, emoji);
    }
  }

  public emitUpdatePushSetting = (channelId, authorId, enabled) => {
    if (this.socket) {
      this.socket.emit('update-channel-setting', channelId, authorId, enabled);
    }
  }

  // on events
  public onChannelHistory(): Observable<any> {
    return this.channelHistory.asObservable();
  }

  public onMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.channelMessage.asObservable();
  }

  public onMessageReply(): Observable<any> {
    return this.channelMessageReply.asObservable();
  }

  public onReaction(): Observable<any> {
    return this.channelReaction.asObservable();
  }

  public onChannelError(): Observable<any> {
    return this.channelError.asObservable();
  }

  public onChannelPostPermissionDenided(): Observable<any> {
    return this.channelPostPermissionDenided.asObservable();
  }

  public onChannelCountUpdate(): Observable<any> {
    return this.channelsCountsSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public onUpdateChannelSetting(): Observable<any> {
    return this.channelSetting.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Below is the page from where I switch between the chat channels. (layout page of user)

```html
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MenuController, ModalController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ChannelTypeService } from 'src/app/services/channel-type.service';
import { ChatService } from 'src/app/services/chat.service';
import { NotificationService } from 'src/app/services/notification.service';
import { ProductGroupsService } from 'src/app/services/product-groups.service';
import { SettingService } from 'src/app/services/setting.service';
import { StorageService } from 'src/app/services/storage.service';
import { NotificationsComponent } from 'src/app/components/notifications/notifications.component';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { SupportPage } from '../../scenes/common/support/support.page';
import { BroadcastService } from 'src/app/services/broadcast.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-layout',
  templateUrl: './user-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-layout.component.scss'],
})

export class UserLayoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  appVersion = environment.version;
  width: number;
  activeChatChannel = '';
  channels: any;
  subscriptions = [];
  channelUpdates = false;
  channelMaintitle: any;
  notification: any = null;
  popoverTimeOver: any;
  
  constructor(
    public storageServ: StorageService,
    private router: Router,
    private chatService: ChatService,
    private platform: Platform,
    private menuCtrl: MenuController,
    private channelService: ChannelTypeService,
    private modalController: ModalController
  ) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.width = platform.width();
      const userId = this.storageServ.get('userId');
      
      if (userId) {
        // establish socket connection
        this.chatService.establishSocketConnection(userId);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllChannels();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
  }

  getAllChannels() {
    this.channelService.getAllChannelTypes().subscribe((channel: any) => {
      this.channels = channel.data.channels;
      this.chatService.pingOnChannelsLoaded();
    });
  }

  activateChatChannel(channel) {
    this.chatService.clearChannelHistory()
    this.activeChatChannel = channel.slug;
    this.storageServ.set('activeSettingChild', channel.slug);
    this.channelMaintitle = channel.settingId.title;
    this.storageServ.set('channelMaintitle', this.channelMaintitle);

    this.channelService.getChannelDetails(channel, 'true').subscribe((channelResponse: any) => {
      const { channel: channelDetails = null } = channelResponse.data;
      if (channelDetails) {
        this.storageServ.set('lockedPageContent', channelDetails.lockedPageContent);
        this.storageServ.set('channelTitle', channelDetails.title);
        this.storageServ.set('channelId', JSON.stringify(channelDetails));
        this.router.navigate(
          [`/user/platinum-chat/${this.activeSetting}/${'channel/' + channel.slug}`],
          { replaceUrl: true }
        );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I'm using this chat service as follow in this component (platinum chat)

```html
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from 'src/app/services/chat.service';
import { ChatThread } from 'src/app/models/chat-thread';
import { PopoverController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { StorageService } from 'src/app/services/storage.service';
import { LoaderService } from 'src/app/services/loader.service';
import { Page } from 'src/app/models/page';
import { CustomScrollDirective } from 'src/app/directives/custom-scroll/custom-scroll.directive';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChannelTypeService } from 'src/app/services/channel-type.service';
import { EmojiPickerComponent } from 'src/app/components/emoji-picker/emoji.component';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-platinum-chat',
  templateUrl: './platinum-chat.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./platinum-chat.page.scss'],
})
export class PlatinumChatPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  [x: string]: any;
  @ViewChild('scrollMe') private myScrollContainer: ElementRef;
  @ViewChildren(CustomScrollDirective) scrollDirective = null;
  public message: string;
  public authorId: any;
  public channel: any;
  public chats: any[];
  public threadChat: any[] = [];
  public isThreadReply = false;
  public parentThreadDetails = null;
  public scrollIntoViewInfiniteLoadEnabled = false;
  public searchedParentThreadId = null;
  public selectedEmoji: any = [];
  public threadDetails: ChatThread;
  public updatedEmoji: any = [];
  public isValidUrl = false;
  public channelTitle: string;
  public lockedPageContent: any;
  public userId = '';
  public userRole = null;
  public channelMaintitle: string;
  public tooltipDetails = '';
  public fileToUpload: File | null;
  public channelError = '';
  public pushEnabled = false;
  public subscriptions = [];
  public page = new Page();
  public channelImages = [];
  public channelIsReadOnlyForUser = false;

  constructor(
    private chatService: ChatService,
    public popoverController: PopoverController,
    public storageServ: StorageService,
    public loaderService: LoaderService,
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private channelService: ChannelTypeService
  ) {
    this.authorId = storageServ.get('authorId');
    this.channel = JSON.parse(storageServ.get('channelId') || '{}');
    this.channelTitle = storageServ.get('channelTitle');
    this.lockedPageContent = storageServ.get('lockedPageContent');
    this.channelMaintitle = storageServ.get('channelMaintitle');
    this.userId = storageServ.get('userId');
    this.userRole = storageServ.get('role') || null;
    this.selectedReactionForThread = this.selectedReactionForThread.bind(this);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.page.offset = 1;
    this.channelImages = [];

    if (this.channel && this.userRole) {
      const { readonly = false, postAllowedRoles = [] } = this.channel;
      if (readonly) {
        this.channelIsReadOnlyForUser = !postAllowedRoles.includes(this.userRole);
      }
    }

    if (this.channel && this.channel._id) {
      this.loaderService.showLoader(`Loading #${this.channel.title.toLowerCase()}`).then(() => {
        this.chatService.emitChannelHistory(this.channel._id, this.page.offset)
      });
    } else {
      this.channelError = 'Channel details not found, please access the page via navigation to gain access!';
    }



    const historySubscription = this.chatService.onChannelHistory().subscribe((channel: any) => {
      console.log("history", channel?.threads)
      if (channel && channel.threads) {
        this.page.totalPages = channel.threadCount / 15; // 15 data load size
        if (!this.scrollIntoViewInfiniteLoadEnabled) {
          this.loaderService.HideLoader();
        }

        if (this.page.offset === 1) {
          const grouppedThreads = this.groupThreadsByDate(channel.threads.reverse());
          this.threadChat = grouppedThreads;
          this.scrollToBottom(10);
        } else {
          this.scrollDirective.first.prepareFor('up');
          const chats = [...channel.threads.reverse(), ...this.threadChat];
          const grouppedThreads = this.groupThreadsByDate(chats);
          this.threadChat = grouppedThreads;
          setTimeout(() => this.scrollDirective.first.restore());
        }

        if (this.scrollIntoViewInfiniteLoadEnabled && this.searchedParentThreadId) {
          this.scrollOnParentThread(this.searchedParentThreadId);
        }
      } else {
        this.loaderService.HideLoader();
        this.threadChat = [];
      }
    });

    const chatSubscription = this.chatService.onMessage().subscribe((thread: any) => {
      /* tslint:disable */
      if (thread && `${this.channel._id}` == `${thread.channelId}`) {
        this.threadChat.push(thread);
        this.scrollToBottom(10);
      }
    });

    const messageReplySubscription = this.chatService.onMessageReply().subscribe((thread: any) => {
      /* tslint:disable */
      if (thread && `${this.channel._id}` == `${thread.channelId}`) {
        this.threadChat.push(thread);
        this.scrollToBottom(10);
      }
    });

    const reactionSubscription = this.chatService.onReaction().subscribe((thread: any) => {
      if (thread) {
        const { _id: threadId } = thread;
        const threadIndex = this.threadChat.findIndex((t) => t._id === threadId);
        if (threadIndex !== -1) {
          this.threadChat[threadIndex] = thread;
        }
      }
    });

    const errorSubscription = this.chatService.onChannelError().subscribe(errorMessage => {
      if (errorMessage) {
        this.loaderService.HideLoader();
        this.channelError = errorMessage;
      } else {
        this.channelError = null;
      }
    });

    const postPermissionDenidedSubscription = this.chatService.onChannelPostPermissionDenided().subscribe(permission => {
      if (permission && permission.denided && permission.channelId === this.channel._id) {
        this.channelIsReadOnlyForUser = true;
        this.channel.id = this.channel._id;
        this.channelService.getChannelDetails(this.channel, 'true').subscribe((channelResponse: any) => {
          const { channel: channelDetails = null } = channelResponse.data;
          if (channelDetails) {
            this.storageServ.set('channelId', JSON.stringify(channelDetails));
          }
        });
      }
    });

    const channelSettingUpdate = this.chatService.onUpdateChannelSetting().subscribe(channel => {
      if (channel) {
        const status = channel && channel.pushUsers && channel.pushUsers.includes(this.userId) || false;
        this.pushEnabled = status;
      }
    });

    this.subscriptions.push(
      chatSubscription,
      reactionSubscription,
      errorSubscription,
      historySubscription,
      channelSettingUpdate,
      postPermissionDenidedSubscription,
      messageReplySubscription
    );
  }

  loadChannelHistoryInfinitely() {
    if (this.page.totalPages > this.page.offset) {
      this.page.offset++;
      if (this.channel && this.channel._id) {
        this.chatService.emitChannelHistory(this.channel._id, this.page.offset);
      }
    }
  }

  scrollOnParentThread(threadId) {
    const el = document.getElementById(`thread-container-${threadId}`);
    if (el) {
      this.loaderService.HideLoader();

      if (!this.scrollIntoViewInfiniteLoadEnabled) {
        this.scrollIntoViewInfiniteLoadEnabled = false;
        this.searchedParentThreadId = null;

        el.classList.add('parent-highlited-thread');
        const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
          const [entry] = entries;
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            setTimeout(() => el.classList.remove('parent-highlited-thread'), 2000);
          }
        });
        intersectionObserver.observe(el);
        el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      } else {
        this.scrollIntoViewInfiniteLoadEnabled = false;
        this.searchedParentThreadId = null;

        el.classList.add('parent-highlited-thread');
        const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
          const [entry] = entries;
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            setTimeout(() => el.classList.remove('parent-highlited-thread'), 2000);
          }
        });
        intersectionObserver.observe(el);
        setTimeout(() => el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' }), 500);
      }
    } else {
      if (this.page.totalPages > this.page.offset) {
        if (!this.scrollIntoViewInfiniteLoadEnabled) {
          this.scrollIntoViewInfiniteLoadEnabled = true;
          this.searchedParentThreadId = threadId;
          this.loaderService.showLoader(`#${this.channel.title.toLowerCase()} conversation loading, please be patient`);
        }
        this.page.offset++;
        this.chatService.emitChannelHistory(this.channel._id, this.page.offset);
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => this.scrollOnParentThread(this.searchedParentThreadId), 50);
      }
    }
  }

  @HostListener('unloaded')
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
    console.log("destoryed..")
  }

  groupThreadsByDate(threads) {
    const threadGroups = threads.reduce((groups, thread) => {
      if (thread.createdAt) {
        /* tslint:disable */
        function isToday(currnetdate) {
          return moment(currnetdate).isSame(moment().startOf('day'), 'day');
        }
        /* tslint:disable */
        function isYesterday(yesterdaydate) {
          return moment(yesterdaydate).isSame(moment().clone().subtract(1, 'days')
            .startOf('day'), 'day');
        }

        const date = isToday(thread.createdAt) ? 'Today' : isYesterday(thread.createdAt) ?
          'Yesterday' : moment.utc(thread.createdAt).local().format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY');

        if (!groups[date]) {
          groups[date] = [];
        }
        groups[date].push(thread);
      }

      return groups;
    }, {});

    /* tslint:disable */
    const uid = function () {
      return Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);
    };

    return Object.keys(threadGroups).reduce((thr, date) => {
      const exist = threads.find(t => t.message && t.message === date);
      if (exist) {
        thr.push(exist, ...threadGroups[date]);
      } else {
        const id = uid();
        thr.push({ message: date, _id: id }, ...threadGroups[date]);
      }
      return thr;
    }, []);
  }

  onUpdatePushSetting(event) {
    this.chatService.emitUpdatePushSetting(this.channel._id, this.userId, event.detail.checked);
  }

  scrollToBottom(time): void {
    let count = 0;
    const activeScrollbar = setInterval(() => {
      try {
        this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
        count += 1;
      } catch (err) { }
      if (count === 5) {
        clearInterval(activeScrollbar);
      }
    }, time);
  }

  send() {
    document.getElementById('fileLoader').click();
  }

  selectedReactionForThread(emojiValue) {
    this.selectedEmoji.push(emojiValue);
    this.chatService.emitReaction(this.channel._id, this.threadDetails._id, this.userId, emojiValue);
  }

  onFileChange(value) {
  }

  handleEmoji(emoji, thread) {
    if (!this.channelIsReadOnlyForUser) {
      this.threadDetails = thread;
      this.selectedReactionForThread(emoji.icon);
    }
  }

  async onGetEmoji(ev: any, item) {
    this.threadDetails = item;
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: EmojiPickerComponent,
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      event: ev,
      translucent: true,
      componentProps: {
        emoji: this.selectedReactionForThread,
      },
    });

    await popover.present();
    await popover.onDidDismiss();
  }

  async sendEmojiMessage(ev: any) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: EmojiPickerComponent,
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      event: ev,
      translucent: true,
      componentProps: {
        emoji: (selectedEmoji) => {
          this.message = !!this.message ? this.message.concat(' ', selectedEmoji) : selectedEmoji;
        },
      },
    });

    await popover.present();
  }

  onSendMessage(event) {
    if (!!this.message && event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
      if (this.isThreadReply && this.parentThreadDetails) {
        this.chatService.emitMessageReply(this.message.trim(), this.parentThreadDetails._id, this.userId, this.channel._id);
        this.message = '';
        this.deactiveThreadReaply();
      } else {
        this.chatService.emitMessage(this.message.trim(), this.userId, this.channel._id);
        this.message = '';
      }
    }
  }

  activeThreadReaply(thread) {
    this.isThreadReply = true;
    this.parentThreadDetails = thread;
  }

  deactiveThreadReaply() {
    this.isThreadReply = false;
    this.parentThreadDetails = null;
  }

  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return item._id;
  }
}
```

The issue is that my BehaviorSubject is being called multiple times when I switch between channels, even I'm unsubscribing my behavior subject from destroy method.

Please keep in mind that I use the same component for all of my chat channels. The destory method for the first component is also called after the init method for the second component (meanwhile switching between the components)

When I call this block of code with a delay, Angular unsubscribes the previous component's behaviour subject, and everything works as expected with only a single time behaviour subject called.

```html
 if (this.channel && this.channel._id) {
      this.loaderService.showLoader(`Loading #${this.channel.title.toLowerCase()}`).then(() => {
        this.chatService.emitChannelHistory(this.channel._id, this.page.offset)
      });
    }
```

Here i have recorded my issue https://www.loom.com/share/3a90ba8e74b44d1085701e359762ad77

I don't understand what is the issue with current codebase.

Can you guys please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

try to take BehaviourSubject  **as Observable** and then try unsubscribing

Comment: Check chat service code. 
I'm already using observables